# Codeigniter redirect not working in __construct method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am checking whether the user is logged in or not in constructor method, if not logged in then redirect to login method  but it is looping infinite time.login method is defined in same controller.

issue:
1)For testing purpose just now I wrote same(login) method in 'Welcome' controller in that case it is working fine and redirect perfectly,after that I commented method in 'Welcome' controller and now login method is uncommented in user controller now it is not working

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        is_logged_in();   // defined in custom helper
        if (!is_logged_in()) {
        redirect(base_url().'User/Login');

        }
    }

    public function login(){

      $this->load->view('loginpage');
    }

}


//code in custom helper

function is_logged_in() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
  $user = $CI->session->userdata('id');
  if (!isset($user)) { 
   return false; 
  } 
 else { 
   return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add url helper in config file.

Answer (score 0):

if your helper returns false your code never reaches the login function of the controller, it always passes by the constructor, which redirects and so on...

change this:

```
    if (!is_logged_in()) {
      $this->login();
    }
```

now it calls the login function, if not logged_in(), otherwise it continues with the controller's index() function

Comment: show your helper, what means didn't work? I checked it quickly in the constructor of a controller and sure it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. This is working fine.

**Controller**

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if(!is_login()){
       redirect(site_url().'/User/login');
    }
}
```

**Helper**

```
function is_login(){
    //Your Logic
    return false;
}
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('your_helper_class_name');
```

Comment: Make sure that your helper is load in config->autoload.php
$autoload['helper'] = array('your_helper_class_name');

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Helper In Controller.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('name');
     $checkLogin = $this->helperName->is_logged_in();   // defined in custom helper
    if (!$checkLogin) {
    redirect(base_url().'User/Login');

    }
}
```

Comment: getting error   Undefined property: User::$Check_loggedIn_helper

Answer (score 0):

I guess you autoload your helper. 
Maybe your helper function need to changed

```
function is_logged_in() {
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $user = $CI->session->userdata('id');
     if (!isset($user) || is_null($user)|| empty($user)) { 
         return false; 
      }else { 
         return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: even i declared helper in construct still same problem i.e not redirecting